# I get Limit Exceeded error when try to reschedule a report

Tags: reporting, limits, schedule

I tried to update the scheduled future run that I have from every weekday to only Tues and Fri. When I try to save, I get the “Limit Exceeded” error message, which doesn’t seem correct as I’m only updating an existing report, and not creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that someone created other scheduled reports scheduled for that hour slot. Check scheduled jobs to see what else is running at that time. If that is the case, then moving it to a different time may help. You could also look for scheduled reports with no future dates that have not been unscheduled. All unscheduled reports count against your limit until they are unscheduled even if the schedule ended years ago. Every place I've worked, I've been able to find some and open some room. Here is a link to documentation on report limits.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Scheduled-Reports-Limitations-Considerations&language=en_US